# (Nginx) + Gunicorn + Flask + Bokeh on Azure with AD

Tags: python, azure, nginx, flask, bokeh

(Apologies: I'm a webapp novice.)

REQUIREMENTS:

- Azure Application Services Web App
- Need Azure AD to authenticate users
- Python Bokeh app to display data webapp once user is authenticated

ATTEMPT:

- I tried wrapping a Flask app around Bokeh using [this example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py)  After many iterations I can't get all traffic to flow to bokeh after authenticating.  I've tried flask redirect(), and my latest iteration involves using requests' get() from the example in the link.

.

```
...
from requests import get
...
@app.route('/')
def bkapp_page():
    script = server_document('https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/bkapp')
    return render_template("embed.html", script=script, template="Flask")

@app.route('/bkapp', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/bkapp/<path:path>")
def bkapp(path):
    return get(f'http://localhost:5006/bkapp/{path}').content
...
```

PROBLEM:
 - Despite many iterations, I can't get the template bokeh renders (which points to javascript the server serves) to point to a path that successfully renders the page.  The best I have done is to get the /bkapp endpoint to not give me a 404 error. 
 - Python Bokeh runs on port 5006 and flask is running on 8000.  I need to forward all traffic destined to bokeh (after authentication) to bokeh through flask. (Azure App Services appear to only allow one open port unless you customize a container, which I'd like to avoid.)

ALTERNATIVES?:

- Sit nginx in front of gunicorn and use a 'reverse proxy' to send all traffic to bokeh.  (Can I do this securely?) But I will have to create a custom container.  I'd rather do this with just gunicorn + flask + bokeh, if possible.
- Feel free to propose anything else.  I'd like to use just gunicorn + flask + bokeh, but if I need a different method, I'll result to that.
  Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Thomas If I remember correctly (and I could be mixing things up) but I'm pretty sure the problem is that flask doesn't properly support forwarding of modern websockets that bokeh  requires.  My first solution was to do nginx + oauth_proxy + bokeh.  I got this working, but it turns out Azure Webapps ahve native  oauth support, so nginx + bokeh alone should be possible. Just build an nginx + bokeh app deploy it to Azure Webapps and turn on AD through the portal (I haven't tested this, but I know the feature is in the portal).

Comment: Hey I'm trying to connect AAD through the portal, do you have any idea what should be the redirect url after sign in?

Comment: sorry it's been a while since iv'e done this stuff. The Redirect url should be the url for your app, but I remember finding the exact path being tricky.  Just try a bunch of options until it works?  But please trust all this with a grain of salt, it's been a while, and I dont want to lead you astray.  Good luck!